# simplify (1 + 2 Cos[2 x])/(Sqrt[3] - 2 Sin[2 x])

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I want to simplify `(1 + 2 Cos[2 x])/(Sqrt[3] - 2 Sin[2 x])` to `Tan[x + Pi/3]`

```
FullSimplify[(1 + 2 Cos[2 x])/(Sqrt[3] - 2 Sin[2 x])]
```

couldn't simplify it. Why doesn't Mathmatica simplify it?

Comment: The best I got was to try FullSimplify[expr1 - expr2] and I get 0.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
rule = x -> y - Pi/3;
left = (1 + 2 Cos[2 x])/(Sqrt[3] - 2 Sin[2 x]) /. rule // TrigExpand //
   TrigReduce 
right = Tan[x + Pi/3] /. rule
```

Out:

```
Tan[y]
Tan[y]
```